# IdhttpServer basic authentication not encrypted?

Tags: delphi, https, indy10

I have a IdHTTPServer with a IdServerIOHandlerSSLOpenSSL which requires a login during connect, by setting the AuthRealm.
This is intended to be used by a government organisation to view specific data.

But they have a massive security system in place, and the web browsers on their network do not accept, or do never receive, the initial Basic Autenthication request. They end up straight to 401: Unauthorized.

I think it is because it seems that the SSL encryption for the connection is not yet established when the initial login / password request is send to the Web browser, and as a result it is blocked. I can see this in my own web browsers as well. https is not yet active.

Is there a way around this? Can I somehow force the SSL connection, before the Basic authentication request is send?
[image: Login Screenshot]

Comment: TLS/SSL is *always* negotiated and established first before even a single HTTP byte is sent for an HTTPS url, including `https://localhost`. You won't even get the basic auth login prompt *unless* TLS/SSL was successfully established.

Comment: Your web browser should be able to explain to you WHY it thinks the connection is "Not Secure".  You are clearly accessing an HTTPS url, so SSL/TLS must be used, but maybe its encryption is too weak or even not present. Or maybe your server lacks a certificate needed to prove its identity to clients. We don't know, since you didn't provide any details about your SSL/TLS setup.

Answer (score 1):

HTTP-based authentication is part of the HTTP request itself.  You have to send the request via an `https:` url to ensure the connection is secured with SSL/TLS *before* the HTTP request is even transmitted.  NEVER ask for HTTP-based authentication using an `http:` url !!! HTTP `BASIC` authentication itself is not secure, as it simply transmits the client's credentials in plain-text using base64.  So the connection has to be secured beforehand.

In any case, the screenshot you have provided clearly shows that an `https:` url is being used.  So yes, SSL/TLS encryption MUST be active on the connection BEFORE the client would send its HTTP request and consequently receive an authentication challenge.  `TIdHTTPServer` would not be able to communicate with any HTTPS client at all if that were not the case.

`TIdHTTPServer` handles HTTPS just fine, provided you have set it up correctly, ie by:

1. having a `TIdServerIOHandlerSSLBase`-derived component assigned to the `TIdHTTPServer.IOHandler` property (which it sounds like you do)
2. setting the `TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketBase(AContext.Connection.IOHandler).PassThrough` property to `False` in the `TIdHTTPServer.OnConnect` event for an SSL/TLS listening port (which `TIdHTTPServer` handles for you by default on the standard HTTPS port, 443).

So, whatever problem you are having is related to something else.  Do you have `TIdHTTPServer` listening on port 443?  Do you have `TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL` configured to use strong encryption, identity validation, etc?  There are many factors at play which you have not provided details about.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the problem I showed is specific to my localhost, probably because something is not set up correctly on my development pc.
Looking at the actual server, yes I now see that SSL is active.

But, on the NZ Police systems, the Basic Authentication is completely ignored, and it immediately goes to 401: Unauthorized.
Sadly, I have no access to their systems, and I do not understand why it happens. I really thought it was because of the SSL not yet establised.
So that is not the case..

Comment: It's likely that they simply don't support `Basic` authentication at all, since its old and inherently unsecure by itself. You might need to use the `TIdHTTPServer.OnParseAuthentication` event to implement a stronger auth scheme.

Comment: Thanks Remy. I have now added an actual html Login web page, which Posts the data back to the server, after which I set the internal 'WebClient' authentication based on the supplied data (in Params).   (IdHTTPServer1.ContextClass := TWebClient)